# How to "auto-open DevTools for popups" in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, developer-tools, ie-developer-tools

I need to check the Network requests from a popup page in the moment it is automatically opened (SCORM 1.2 launch).
I know that I can do this in Google Chrome by setting the *Auto-open DevTools for popups* checkbox, but I need it for IE 11.

I cannot use fiddler, as the computer is basically a terminal with IE 11 only and the installation of software is prohibited.

Any help or suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: If your popup(showModalDialog) has an input element or an anchor element on it you can right click on those elements and select "Inspect Element" from the context menu to display the dev tool. However you need to turn the Network capture on fist and then refresh the page to list the Network traffic. Alternatively, If using a domain network, your proxy logs should be able to list your requests and responses.

Comment: If you have access to the popup script, and it is using showModalDialog, change the javascript to use window.open instead (for testing) then you can display the dev tool using the Command bar button or the f12 key or the context menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
Unfortunatelly they're not what I'm looking for as:
1- The popup is controlled by the SCORM engine, so I have no access to it.
2- By the time I press F12 on the new window is too late to register the first request.

Comment: You server or proxy logs should show the request streams.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no such option in F12 to auto popup.

The only thing, without installing something, I can think of is that you attach to the page from the `IEChooser.exe` (it might be `F12Chooser.exe` depending on the Windows version) which is inbox on Windows. You can find it at:

`C:\Windows\System32\F12` `C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe`

When you run it you'll see all the targets the tools that are hosting mshtml (inc IE). Pick the target you want to debug and then run your scenario. Hopefully the popup will be created in the same process as the tab you attached to. If that's the case then all the network traffic will be in the F12 Chooser.

(This is an old question but leaving an answer as maybe it will help someone else in the future.)